# Manipulate Data from httpClient in Angular

Tags: angular

I am requesting an JSON from an API with this code:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.exampleDatabase = new ExampleHttpDatabase(this._httpClient);

        // If the user changes the sort order, reset back to the first page.
        this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);

        merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
            .pipe(
                startWith({}),
                switchMap(() => {
                    this.isLoadingResults = true;
                    return this.exampleDatabase!.getRepoIssues(
                        this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex);
                }),
                map(data => {
                    // Flip flag to show that loading has finished.
                    this.isLoadingResults = false;
                    this.isRateLimitReached = false;
                    this.resultsLength = data.total_count;

                    console.log(data['items']);
                    return data['items'];
                }),
                catchError(() => {
                    this.isLoadingResults = false;
                    // Catch if the GitHub API has reached its rate limit. Return empty data.
                    this.isRateLimitReached = true;
                    return observableOf([]);
                })
            ).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
    }
}

/** An example database that the data source uses to retrieve data for the table. */
export class ExampleHttpDatabase {
    constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    getRepoIssues(sort: string, order: string, page: number): Observable<ContactInterface> {
        var href = '/schuhe-store/history';

        console.log(environment.production);

        if(environment.production === false) {
            href = 'https://sales.dailysshop.com/schuhe-store/history';
        }

        const requestUrl =
            `${href}?sort=${sort}&order=${order}&page=${page + 1}`;

        return this._httpClient.get<ContactInterface>(requestUrl);
    }
}
```

The result of the API looks like:

```
{"itemsPerPage":"25","page":"1","total_count":3032,"items":[{"id":"12634","timestamp":"2021-09-04T23:04:47+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"1"},{"id":"12633","timestamp":"2021-09-04T22:50:39+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"1"},{"id":"12632","timestamp":"2021-09-04T22:36:37+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12631","timestamp":"2021-09-04T22:17:52+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12630","timestamp":"2021-09-04T22:04:59+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12629","timestamp":"2021-09-04T21:50:41+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12628","timestamp":"2021-09-04T21:35:49+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"1"},{"id":"12627","timestamp":"2021-09-04T21:17:01+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12626","timestamp":"2021-09-04T21:05:23+02:00","type":"delta","rows":"165","duration":"0"},{"id":"12625","timestamp":"2021-09-04T21:05:00+02:00","type":"full","rows":"4677","duration":"46"},{"id":"12624","timestamp":"2021-09-04T21:03:49+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12623","timestamp":"2021-09-04T20:50:18+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12622","timestamp":"2021-09-04T20:36:42+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12621","timestamp":"2021-09-04T20:15:30+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12620","timestamp":"2021-09-04T20:03:46+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12619","timestamp":"2021-09-04T19:50:21+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12618","timestamp":"2021-09-04T19:36:48+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"1"},{"id":"12617","timestamp":"2021-09-04T19:18:04+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12616","timestamp":"2021-09-04T19:05:24+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12615","timestamp":"2021-09-04T18:51:54+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"1"},{"id":"12614","timestamp":"2021-09-04T18:37:36+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"1"},{"id":"12613","timestamp":"2021-09-04T18:21:30+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12612","timestamp":"2021-09-04T18:06:28+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"2"},{"id":"12611","timestamp":"2021-09-04T17:54:05+02:00","type":"import","rows":"1","duration":"13"},{"id":"12610","timestamp":"2021-09-04T17:42:08+02:00","type":"import","rows":"0","duration":"1"}],"incomplete_results":false}
```

My HTML is:

```
<div class="mat-table-container">
    <tc-table-settings [columns]="_columns" [(selectedColumns)]="_columnList">
        <terra-group-function [disableExecution]="false">
            <terra-text-input #input [inputName]="'Text'"></terra-text-input>
        </terra-group-function>

    </tc-table-settings>

    <mat-table
        #table="matTable"
        mat-table
        class="w-100"
        [dataSource]="data"
        matSort
        matSortActive="id"
        matSortDirection="desc"
        matSortDisableClear
    >
        <ng-container *ngFor="let column of _columns">
            <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column.key" [ngSwitch]="column.key">
                <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
                    <mat-header-cell mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column.label }}</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let contact">{{ contact[column.key] }}</mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="_columnList"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: _columnList;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>

    <terra-no-result-notice
        *ngIf="resultsLength === 0"
        [inputButtons]="_noResultButtons"
        [inputTextPrimary]="'noResult' | translate: lang"
        [inputTextSecondary]="'test' | translate: lang"
    >
    </terra-no-result-notice>
    <mat-paginator
            [length]="resultsLength"
            [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 250, 500]"
            showFirstLastButtons
            aria-label="Select page of periodic elements"
            [disabled]="resultsLength === 0">
    </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

*I have attached the HTML code now.*

I would like convert the timestamp to a readable format (i.e. DD.MM.YYYY, HH:II), can I do this with a mutator or with a pipe and map?

Can someone help me to get this done?

Comment: What is your issue? Displaying a date as string in a nice format? If so, what did you try?

Comment: Hi @GaëlJ,

correct. I updated the question with added HTML template.

Kind regards
Henning

Answer (score 2):

Use the Angular Date Pipe.

`item.timestamp | date:'medium'`

Comment: Hi @Nikhil-v-s, I want not to create the columns manually in my html.

Kind regards
Henning

Answer (score -1):

How is your ContactInterface?

If you have already defined your ContactInterface in this way, you would have the property "timestamp" as Date, so it would be "readable" format:

```
export interface ContactInterface {
    itemsPerPage:       string;
    page:               string;
    total_count:        number;
    items:              Item[];
    incomplete_results: boolean;
}

export interface Item {
    id:        string;
    timestamp: Date;
    type:      Type;
    rows:      string;
    duration:  string;
}

export enum Type {
    Delta = "delta",
    Full = "full",
    Import = "import",
}
```

After that, you only have to use it as "Date" type in the TS (even with [some libraries](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/) for working with Date as "Day.js"), and you can use the Date pipes in html, as you can see [HERE](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: Hi Juan, I Will change it in my interface. I don't have any column defined in my material table, it is generated in a loop. Can I modify the date format without creating the columns manually? And how can I can output the enum value in the table, @juan-berzosa-tejero?

Comment: In order to get more help by someone, It would be good you edit your first question and add that piece of your HTML code.

Comment: Hi @juan-berzosa-tejero, just done.

Kind regards
Henning